# Why is my RHEL6 x86_64 server trying to install libselinux.i686?

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, rhel6

Just did a fresh install using the RHEL 6 DVD on a test VirtualBox server:

```
[root@bt-rhel6-1 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.1 (Santiago)
```

I am certain it's an x86_64 machine:

```
[root@bt-rhel6-1 ~]# uname -a
Linux bt-rhel6-1.local 2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue May 10 15:42:40 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And no other i686 packages are installed:

```
[root@bt-rhel6-1 ~]# rpm -qa | grep i686
[root@bt-rhel6-1 ~]# rpm -qa | grep x86_64 | wc -l
331
```

But when I do `yum update`:

```
[root@bt-rhel6-1 ~]# yum update 2>&1 | grep i686
---> Package libselinux.i686 0:2.0.94-5.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.1) for package: libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.0) for package: libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libdl.so.2 for package: libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.8) for package: libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) for package: libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4) for package: libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) for package: libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.4) for package: libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.3) for package: libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2) for package: libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) for package: libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.2) for package: libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) for package: libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) for package: libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6 for package: libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: ld-linux.so.2(GLIBC_2.3) for package: libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: ld-linux.so.2 for package: libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.47.el6_2.5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) for package: glibc-2.12-1.47.el6_2.5.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so for package: glibc-2.12-1.47.el6_2.5.i686
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.12.9-11.el6 will be installed
Error: Protected multilib versions: libselinux-2.0.94-5.2.el6.x86_64 != libselinux-2.0.94-5.el6.i686
```

Here are my repositories:

```
[root@bt-rhel6-1 ~]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
repo id                                                                           repo name                                                                                                              status
epel                                                                              Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                                                         6,893
rhel-x86_64-server-6                                                              Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (v. 6 for 64-bit x86_64)                                                               6,806
repolist: 13,699
```

What gives?

Comment: Can you post the full output of `yum -v update`? In general you should probably be using `yum upgrade` so that the obsolete logic is invoked as well.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like the problem is with the `selinux-ruby` that is installed requiring that specific package. I'll update the issue Monday morning since I'm heading out of the office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to an `selinux-ruby` package bug.

`yum -v update` command that @Mark recommended helped me figure that out. I was able to get around it by manually installing a newer package and all was good.